# React Parsing failed ,Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am trying to create a Dynamic Material UI Flex box that generate a new row based on backend . my idea is to close the current outer Box and create a new one based on a flag

so i write the following code

```
    <Box p="1em">
      <Box display="flex">
        {tabs.map((t, index) => {
          return (
            <>

              <Box flex={resourcesTabs[index][0] == null ? 1 : resourcesTabs[index][0]['width_class']} ml="1em">

                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>{t}</Typography>

                {resourcesFields[index] && resourcesFields[index].map((f, index) =>
                  generateInputField(f, index)
                )}
              </Box>

              {resourcesTabs[index][0]['new_line_after'] && </Box><Box display="flex">}

            </>

          );


        })}

      </Box>
    </Box>
```

But i recive the following Error

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token
```

as it complain about close open tags dynamic for this line

```
          {resourcesTabs[index][0]['new_line_after'] && (</Box><Box display="flex">}
```

any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sneaky parenthesis:

```
{resourcesTabs[index][0]['new_line_after'] &&   => ( <=   </Box><Box display="flex">}
```

Comment: thanks for your note , its not the problem i remove it and still the same

Comment: this will work but will not help with my case as i need to generate a new line Box and fill it with sub. boxes

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by replace box with grid as the following code

```
     <div style={{ padding: 10 }}>

      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {tabs.map((t, index) => {

          return (
            <>
              <Grid item xs={resourcesTabs[index][0] == null ? 6 : resourcesTabs[index][0]['width_class']} >

                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>{t}</Typography>

                {resourcesFields[index] && resourcesFields[index].map((f, index) =>
                  generateInputField(f, index)
                )}
              </Grid>


            </>

          );


        }

        )}

      </Grid>
      </div>
```